# How do I get the bytes array when I have a uri object in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, io, xamarin.android

I want to register a custom file association and process the file. To process the file I need the bytes array behind the file.

I successfully registered myself for a custom `.xmoo` extension via:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "application/*", DataPathPattern = "*.xmoo")]  
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        Android.Net.Uri fileUri = Intent.Data;
```

Now, I'm however at a loss of how I get the bytes array from the Uri. What's the canonical way to read the bytes?

Comment: read the `Uri`'s input stream, refer to `ContentResolver` API for more details

Comment: is it useful `var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
var httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
httpClient.BaseAddress = baseUri;
return await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(baseUri);`

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong converting it to a memory stream and then to byte array might do the trick:

Something like this:

```
public byte[] UriToByteArrayConverter(Android.Net.Uri uri)
{
  Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);   
  byte[] byteArray;

  using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
     stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
     byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
  }
    return byteArray;
}
```

In case it does not work kindly revert.